# How to compare arbitrary tables for differences in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

**I'm trying to compare data from two tables with identical columns, looking for differences.** One table represents the 'live' data, and the other is effectively an archive:

Tables:  Live, Archive

Columns: Id, Name, Age, Gender

So, for example, we could have the live data:

```
Id Name      Age Gender
-- --------- --- ------
1  Alan      31  Male
2  Betty     22  Female
```

and the archive could be:

```
Id Name      Age Gender
-- --------- --- ------
1  Alan      30  Male
2  Lizzy     20  Female
```

What I want to do is find out how the data in these two tables has changed, for any given Id value. So if I ran the query against Id=1, I would ideally like this result:

```
Column Live    Archive
------ ------- --------
Age    31      30
```

And for Id=2:

```
Column Live    Archive
------ ------- --------
Name   Betty   Lizzy
Age    22      20
```

The twist is that I'd like to run this query against *any* two tables (knowing that they'll have identical columns), so I can't name the columns in the query.

I suspect this is *theoretically* possible to pull off because you can ask the sqlite DB itself for the columns for any given table - or at least you can using a pragma.

**Am I trying to do way too much here?** If so, **is it possible to get the types of results I'm looking for if I do explicitly name the columns in the query** (e.g. build the query string at runtime after querying the table's column names)?